# Is HTML5 a programming language?

Tags: html

Nowadays, we can use HTML5 to make apps, as in android, in firefox os, iPhone, Blackberry and others. But, I heard that HTML is a Markup language, not for programming.
Even with App features, HTML continues to being **only** a markup language?

Comment: You could look up these terms in Wikipedia if nothing else.

Comment: It's certainly more than just a markup language, since it also defines interfaces for e.g. history and storage APIs useable in JavaScript. But those are only *descriptions*, much like the DOM API, it's not a language.

Comment: Must-see: https://github.com/SirPepe/SpecGraph

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short Answer:** No.

**Long Answer**: No, it isn't. HTML as defined by the standard is just a markup language, exactly as it was in its previous versions.

*But what does that mean?* It means that it is supposed to *structure* your data allowing you also to define semantics with the use of markers, but it cannot process or modify your data as you would do using a programming language. Also it has no concept of *input* or *output* as is the case in programming languages​​, where you get an input to analyze and produce an output.

By the way HTML5 is coming out alongside a wider interest for the web and also stronger technologies (such as newer versions of javascript and css) which make new web applications even more powerful and limitless.

Please, read [this great resource](http://diveintohtml5.info/) to learn more about HTML5.

Answer (score 15):

Programming languages have certain features, like branching, looping, that sort of thing, that HTML5 lacks. HTML5 defines markup for some interactive features, but the markup is almost entirely static (there's *some* interaction implied in the definition of `select` elements and such). A lot of "HTML5" features you hear about aren't HTML5 at all, but rather things you can do with JavaScript (a programming language) in a modestly-capable browser.

HTML5 is increasingly taking over (or *has* taken over) the role of defining both the structure of web pages *and* the API to interacting with them from a programming language. That used to be quite separate, in the DOM specs, but a lot of that is now being folded into the HTML5 specification. But again, that's just defining APIs. The actual coding using those APIs requires (in almost all cases) an actual programming language.

Comment: Good answer - I would also say that a "*HTML5 app* is always at least a combination of HTML5, CSS and JavaScript not only a HTML5 page itself. Without CSS and JavaScript (or some server side interaction) it's still more a static page than an app.

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 is considered a technology.
Yes, there is 5th release of HTML markup language but probably you didn't mean that.

HTML5 is more considered to be a technology including HTML,CSS3 and javascript and most of all their support in tools like browsers. So as a matter of fact it can be considered as something that requires programming.

Comment: html5 is the next version of html4. its not a technology anymore then html4 is. <nav> and section elements dont change anything. Agree, some tools out there are all confused and call flash apps ajax but thats not the definition of html5.

Comment: Indeed, however as I mentioned it's used in common sense as technology and its more popular in the above context. I just sense where the confusion of the question above comes.

Comment: @user1721135 no but when someone says 'let's make this and HTML5 app', they generally mean let's make this an HTML5/CSS/Javascript app. Strictly speaking you're right, but common usage includes CSS and JS.

Comment: there are a lot of mouthbreathers in suits who will call css html5 or are hiring "html5" developers. HTML5 enebles canvas and with js you can make games. i think thats one of the reasons its confused.

Answer (score 0):

Programming do not means Turing Complete Language. It's a linguistic problem, programing means to plan something, and this Html does very well.

program (n.)

1630s, "public notice," from Late Latin programma "proclamation, edict," from Greek programma "a written public notice," from stem of prographein "to write publicly," from pro "forth" (see pro-) + graphein "to write" (see -graphy).

The meaning "written or printed list of pieces at a concert, playbill" is recorded by 1805 and retains the original sense. The sense of "broadcasting presentation" is from 1923.

The general sense of "a definite plan or scheme, method of operation or line of procedure prepared or announced beforehand" is recorded from 1837. The computer sense of "series of coded instructions which directs a computer in carrying out a specific task: is from 1945.

The sense of "objects or events suggested by music" is from 1854 (program music is attested by 1877). Spelling programme, established in Britain, is from French in modern use and began to be used early 19c., originally especially in the "playbill" sense.

[source](https://www.etymonline.com/word/program#:%7E:text=program%20(n.),%22%20(see%20-graphy))